# Entity Framework - query inside a where statement

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario where I need to fetch list of string values from a table.

I need to query the `Subject` table and get list of subjects:

```
EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
emp.subjects = from x in EmpDB.subjects
                join y in EmpDB.employeeInfo 
                 on x.subjectCode equals y.subjectCode select new
   {
    x.subjectTitle,
   }.toList();
```

I have an employee ID which I need to query the `EmployeeDetails` table and get `SubjectCodes` of that particular `Employee ID`, and using those subject codes, I need to query the `Subject` table and get the subject values.

Comment: You can use either `join` with `equals` or `Any()` to achieve the objective, but seem the second query is still incomplete.

Comment: I have edited my post, i tried in the above way but its throwing compile errors..

Comment: What is `emp.subjects` & `x.subjectTitle` property type? You're returning `select new` as anonymous type but the property may have different type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in EmployeeDetails class you have property Subjects with List.

```
EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
emp.subjects = (from x in EmpDB.subjects
                join y in EmpDB.employeeInfo on x.subjectCode equals y.subjectCode
                where y.EmployeeId = <<your ID>>  // Employee ID you searching 
                  select x.subjectTitle).ToList();
```

Comment: after join statement, the where statement isn't working, i dont see intellinsense popping up where after join and the consecutive lines of code isn't compiling.... 'Invalid expression term 'where' is the error..